# creating a playing card Class Python

Tags: python, class, attributes, comparison

I created a playing card object that has certain attributes of rank, suite and blackjack value.

The blackjack value part keep getting a TypeError that says I can't compare between instances of `list` and `int`. I'm not sure how to resolve (how to/if I can compare just the index of the list and then give it the blackjack value based on its index)?

Does the if/elif block belong within the bjValue() function or in the **init**() function?

Here's my code:

```
class Card:

    """playing card object where numeric rank, suit and blackjack values are stored"""

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
        self.ranks = [None, "Ace", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
       self.suits = {"d": "Diamonds",
                   "c": "Clubs",
                   "h": "Hearts",
                   "s": "Spades"}




    def getRank(self):
        """returns the rank of the card"""
        return self.rank

    def getSuit(self):

        return self.suits.get(self.suit)

    def bjValue(self):

        if self.rank > 1 or self.rank < 11:
            self.value = self.rank

        elif self.rank == "Ace":
            self.value = 1

        elif self.rank == "Jack" or self.ranks == "Queen" or self.ranks == "King":
            self.value = 10


        return self.value


    def __str__(self):

        return "%s of %s" % (self.ranks[self.rank], self.suits.get(self.suit))





c1 = Card(1,"s")
c2 = Card(11,"d")
print(c1) #expect Ace of Spades
print(c2) #expect Jack of Diamonds

c3 = Card(5,"c") #expect 5 of clubs
print(c3.getRank())
print(c3.getSuit()) #expect Five
print(c3.bjValue()) #expect 5
print(c3)

c4 = Card(1,"s")
print(c4)
```

Edit: So, I fixed my typo and I'm not getting anymore errors but I'm still getting the incorrect blackjack value for the Jack, Queen and King cards  (I get their blackjack value back as their rank even though i have the if statement) and I don't understand where the flaw in my logic is...

Comment: can you please share the exact stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're a beginner. Let's consider the error it's giving you:

```
    if self.ranks > 1 or self.ranks < 11:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

There's a typo in your `bjValue` function:

```
if self.ranks > 1 or self.ranks < 11:
    self.value = self.ranks
```

You're comparing to the `ranks` list, instead of the actual (current) `rank` value.

What you meant was probably:

```
if self.rank > 1 or self.rank < 11:
    self.value = self.ranks[self.rank]
```

**Edit**

Based on your comment, what I suspect you want is something like this.

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.ranks = [None, "Ace", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
        self.rank = self.ranks[rank]
        self.suits = {"d": "Diamonds", "c": "Clubs", "h": "Hearts", "s": "Spades"}
        self.suit = self.suits[suit]
        self.value = -1

    def getRank(self):
        return self.rank

    def getSuit(self):
        return self.suit

    def bjValue(self):
        if self.rank == "Ace":
            self.value = 1
        elif self.rank == "Jack" or self.rank == "Queen" or self.rank == "King":
            self.value = 10
        elif type(self.rank) is int:
            if self.rank > 1 and self.rank < 11:
                self.value = self.ranks[self.rank]
        return self.value
```

*Unless you want to be able to change the rank or suit on any already created cards, then I would recommend moving the if statements from `bjValue` into `__init__`.*

Comment: yes! omg- thank you for pointing that out- {I was sort of worried about using .rank and .ranks in the beginning when I was starting worried I'd mix them up & I did!! } ... Thank you!!

Comment: @KindeR66 You're welcome! If you would mark the answer as accepted, that would make me equally happy! :)

Comment: I just edited my question because I'm still having a problem with this(& I' m hoping I'll maybe get some help)- so, I fixed that & I'm not getting anymore errors but I'm still getting the incorrect value for the Jack, Queen and King playing cards (just getting their name back)

Comment: @KindeR66 So just to make sure I get it. When you have the Jack then `bjValue()` returns `Jack` but you want it to return `11` or ? If so what's the difference between `getRank()` and `bjValue()` ?

Comment: hey- sorry I've been away, I'm still working on this actually (I moved on past this problem to address more complex parts of this game)- so, basically, I'm trying to give these blackjack values (the self.value variable) so I want Jack, Queen and King to have bjValue() of 10 each (instead of 11,12 and 13) - that's why I have this line `elif self.rank == "Jack" or self.rank == "Queen" or self.rank == "King":
            self.value = 10` which isn't working @Vallentin

Comment: omg, that's so smart to assign a value of -1! - that totally takes care of the problem- Ah! why didn't I think of that ;-) ... Thank u so much! Cheers! @Vallentin

Comment: and to test using type as well- omg, so smart- thank u, I learned more from you on this than in class :-) @Vallentin - Thank u!

Comment: Just keep learning! I've been using Python for ages, and I still learn new stuff every other day! :)